# Bing Maps - UK Postcode to Map

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to do is show a small bing generated map centred on a uk postcode through the ajax API. I am sure this is possible; what i can't find in the Bing Map documentation how to convert a UK Postcode into coordinates that I can plug into the Maps Ajax Control. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
  function GetMap()
  {   

     var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), 
                       {credentials: "MyKeyHere",
                        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5),
                        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                        zoom: 7});
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Bing Maps REST Locations service to geocode the postcode, and then create a map centred on the resulting coordinate location:

For example, to geocode the postcode "NR2 4TE":
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/NR24TE?key=YourBingMapsKey

Look in the coordinates property of the "point" object returned to get the latitude and longitude coordinates on which to centre your map.

Comment: Out of the office tomorrow will give it a go on monday. Thanks

Comment: Gives a lot more detail back but delivers the two important numbers. Thanks :)